# How can I keep pizza warm on the trip home?

Tags: food, temperature

Many of you know that problem, after work you go and get some "Pizza to go" from the Italian restaurant. When you arrive at home it is not really warm anymore no matter whether you put it in a bag or not. Does anyone know a lifehack which could help me keeping it warmer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You know the insulated bags used to keep groceries cold on the trip home? They look like this or similar:

[image]

They also work to keep things warm. If you have one big enough for pizza, put it in the bag preferably in the shop, get as much air out as possible, and put it in your car (which should be warmed up first in winter) on one of the seats, then put a towel/folded blanket over it. Eat as soon as possible after arriving at your destination.

Comment: U think they keep warm also? Humm u sure about it? I'll give it a try.

Comment: @FelixLahmer Insulation works both ways. It's used to create a barrier to try and keep the temperature outside from affecting what's inside as much as possible. Like double-pane windows in a house.

Comment: Cool I didn't know you could buy these.

Comment: The bag might cause condensation in the pizza box which would make the pie soggy etc.

Comment: Pizza delivery guys use a bigger kind of this bag or a box which does the same, when delivering by bicycle or scooter (which is the norm in many places.)

Answer (score 14):

Get an old blanket and lay it over the pizza boxes on the seat, covering the sides of the boxes if possible. If the blanket is large enough, fold it first so that you have 2 or 4 layers keeping your pizza hot.

I have found this to be *more effective* than insulated bags, especially when the blanket is doubled up.

<sub><sup>*(Old blanket so that if there is sauce/grease on the outside, you're not out your favorite blanket)</sup></sub>

Comment: Yes I agree this is better than an insulated bag as the air can still circulate so you don't get condensation which leads to a soggy pizza - and no one likes a soggy pizza!

Comment: Could you put something warm on top of the blanket as well?

Comment: @TrajanEspelien Potentially, but I don't see it being especially effective since it will lose its heat into the car rather into the pizza.

Answer (score 12):

I'm a pizza shop owner. I often sell "half baked" pizzas to customers who want to finish baking it at home.  Ten minutes in the oven and you have a wonderful pizza shop flavor and the warm pizza you are craving.  Ask your favorite shop to "half bake" your pie for you or come to my shop and I will fix u up;)

Comment: Welcome to the lifehacks community. Good suggestion, but very careful with advertising (both self-advertising and/or advertising other products). :-D

Comment: I think she meant it more as a joke.

Answer (score 4):

If your car has a seat warmer (most modern ones do), turn it on and put the pizza (in the box) on the seat. If you really want warm pizza, put a jacket/blanket/something over it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest couple of more hacks to keep the pizza warm on the way home:

1. Hot water bottle - Works if you happen to be travelling from home or somewhere with a kettle to fill it up.
2. Picnic cool box if you have one, as it also keep the warmth inside.

Comment: Hi user31728, Welcome to Lifehacks. Don't forget to visit [tour] and [help] to find out how to get the most from this Q and A site.